# LaTeX Workshop in VSCode failed to compile

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, compilation-error, vscode

I am trying to use LaTeX Workshop in VSCode to compile my tex file. I have no idea why it can not successfully compile it. The error log is as follows:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.8.7)  7 AUG 2021 12:26
entering extended mode
**d:/DATA/TEX/ShadowTaint/paper.tex
(d:/DATA/TEX/ShadowTaint/paper.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01>
L3 programming layer <2021-06-01> (acmart.cls
Document Class: acmart 2020/10/25 v1.74 Typesetting articles for the Association for Computing Machinery
(F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xkeyval\xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkeyval.tex (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xkeyval\keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count182
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xstring\xstring.sty (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/xstring\xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count183
\decimalpart=\count184
)
Package: xstring 2021/07/21 v1.84 String manipulations (CT)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
Package acmart Info: Not using screen mode on input line 73.
Package acmart Info: Using breaking urls on hyphens on input line 81.
Package acmart Info: Requiring acmthm on input line 89.
Package acmart Info: Not using review mode on input line 98.
Package acmart Info: Not using authorversion mode on input line 106.
Package acmart Info: Not using nonacm mode on input line 118.
Package acmart Info: Explicitly selecting natbib mode on input line 130.
Package acmart Info: Not using anonymous mode on input line 138.
Package acmart Info: Not using timestamp mode on input line 146.
Package acmart Info: Not using authordraft mode on input line 156.
Package acmart Info: Using review mode on input line 165.
Package acmart Info: Using anonymous mode on input line 165.
Class acmart Info: Using format sigconf, number 4 on input line 165.
Class acmart Info: Using fontsize 9pt on input line 249.
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amscls\amsart.cls
Document Class: amsart 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\linespacing=\dimen138
\normalparindent=\dimen139
\normaltopskip=\skip47
(F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2021/04/20 v2.17j AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip48

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks18
\ex@=\dimen140
)) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen141
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count185
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count186
\leftroot@=\count187
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count188
\DOTSCASE@=\count189
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box50
\strutbox@=\box51
\big@size=\dimen142
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count190
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count191
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count192
\dspbrk@lvl=\count193
\tag@help=\toks19
\row@=\count194
\column@=\count195
\maxfields@=\count196
\andhelp@=\toks20
\eqnshift@=\dimen143
\alignsep@=\dimen144
\tagshift@=\dimen145
\tagwidth@=\dimen146
\totwidth@=\dimen147
\lineht@=\dimen148
\@envbody=\toks21
\multlinegap=\skip49
\multlinetaggap=\skip50
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks22
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 397.
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
)
\copyins=\insert199
\abstractbox=\box52
\listisep=\skip51
\c@part=\count197
\c@section=\count198
\c@subsection=\count266
\c@subsubsection=\count267
\c@paragraph=\count268
\c@subparagraph=\count269
\c@figure=\count270
\c@table=\count271
\abovecaptionskip=\skip52
\belowcaptionskip=\skip53
\captionindent=\dimen149
\thm@style=\toks23
\thm@bodyfont=\toks24
\thm@headfont=\toks25
\thm@notefont=\toks26
\thm@headpunct=\toks27
\thm@preskip=\skip54
\thm@postskip=\skip55
\thm@headsep=\skip56
\dth@everypar=\toks28
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.sty
Package: microtype 2021/03/14 v2.8c Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
\MT@toks=\toks29
\MT@count=\count272
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 790.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen150
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1374.
\MT@listname@count=\count273
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype-pdftex.def
File: microtype-pdftex.def 2021/03/14 v2.8c Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 915.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 915.
\MT@outer@space=\skip57
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/microtype\microtype.cfg
File: microtype.cfg 2021/03/14 v2.8c microtype main configuration file (RS)
)) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count274
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/booktabs\booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2020/01/12 v1.61803398 Publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen151
\lightrulewidth=\dimen152
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen153
\belowrulesep=\dimen154
\belowbottomsep=\dimen155
\aboverulesep=\dimen156
\abovetopsep=\dimen157
\cmidrulesep=\dimen158
\cmidrulekern=\dimen159
\defaultaddspace=\dimen160
\@cmidla=\count275
\@cmidlb=\count276
\@aboverulesep=\dimen161
\@belowrulesep=\dimen162
\@thisruleclass=\count277
\@lastruleclass=\count278
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen163
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/refcount\refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/totpages\totpages.sty
Package: totpages 2005/09/19 v2.00 Totpages Package (muewi)
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/everyshi\everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2020/11/18 v4.00 EveryShipout Package
)) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/environ\environ.sty
Package: environ 2014/05/04 v0.3 A new way to define environments
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/trimspaces\trimspaces.sty
Package: trimspaces 2009/09/17 v1.1 Trim spaces around a token list
)) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/textcase\textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip58
\bibsep=\skip59
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count279
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-05 v7.00l Hypertext links for LaTeX
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdftexcmds\pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvsetkeys\kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/kvdefinekeys\kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/pdfescape\pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hycolor\hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/letltxmacro\letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/auxhook\auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/kvoptions\kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen164
\Hy@linkcounter=\count280
\Hy@pagecounter=\count281
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-05 v7.00l Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-05 v7.00l Hyperref: patches for babel languages
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/intcalc\intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count282
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-05 v7.00l Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksnumbered' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4073.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count283
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip17
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen165
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bitset\bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/bigintcalc\bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count284
\Field@Width=\dimen166
\Fld@charsize=\dimen167
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6096.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count285
\c@Item=\count286
\c@Hfootnote=\count287
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperref\hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2021-06-05 v7.00l Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count288
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count289
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/rerunfilecheck\rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/uniquecounter\uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 286.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip60
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/hyperxmp\hyperxmp.sty
Package: hyperxmp 2020/11/22 v5.9 Store hyperref metadata in XMP format
\hyxmp@aep@toks=\toks30
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/stringenc\stringenc.sty
Package: stringenc 2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/ifmtarg\ifmtarg.sty
Package: ifmtarg 2018/04/16 v1.2b check for an empty argument
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2020/11/24 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/oberdiek\ifdraft.sty
Package: ifdraft 2016/05/16 v1.4 Detect class options draft and final (HO)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen168
\Gin@req@width=\dimen169
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/geometry\geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2020/01/02 v5.9 Page Geometry
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2019/10/25 v1.7 ifvtex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)

...

Package array Warning: Column V is already defined on input line 9.

) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks82
\inpenc@posthook=\toks83
) (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/listings\lstlang1.sty
File: lstlang1.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d listings language file
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfdisplaydoctitle' set `true' on input line 192.
\c@theorem=\count431
 (F:\MiKTeX\tex/latex/preprint\balance.sty
Package: balance 1999/02/23 4.3 (PWD)
\oldvsize=\dimen354
) Excluding comment 'screenonly' Include comment 'printonly' Excluding comment 'anonsuppress' Excluding comment 'acks'

Package csquotes Warning: Load 'inputenc' before 'csquotes' on input line 192.

Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... none found.
runsystem(for ^%i in (pygmentize.exe pygmentize.bat pygmentize.cmd) do set > paper.aex <nul: /p x=^%~$PATH:i>> paper.aex)...disabled (restricted).
```

My tex file is downloaded from overleaf. It looks like (The following content is simplified but having the same issue):

```
\documentclass[sigconf,review, anonymous]{acmart}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
    \normalfont B\kern-0.5em{\scshape i\kern-0.25em b}\kern-0.8em\TeX}}}

% \setcopyright{acmcopyright}
% \copyrightyear{2021}
% \acmYear{2021}
% \acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

%% These commands are for a PROCEEDINGS abstract or paper.
\acmConference[ISSTA 2021]{ACM SIGSOFT International Symposium on Software Testing and Analysis}{12-16 July, 2021}{ Aarhus, Denmark}
\acmBooktitle{ISSTA'21: ACM SIGSOFT International Symposium on Software Testing and Analysis, 12-16 July, 2021, Aarhus, Denmark}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-XXXX-X/18/06}

\settopmatter{printacmref=false, printccs=false, printfolios=false}
\setcopyright{none} 
\renewcommand\footnotetextcopyrightpermission[1]{}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\acmConference[ESEC/FSE 2020]{The 28th ACM Joint European Software Engineering Conference and Symposium on the Foundations of Software Engineering}{8 - 13 November, 2020}{Sacramento, California, United States}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm
% \usepackage{algorithmicx}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
% \usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{myDef}{Definition}
%\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\algblock{Input}{EndInput}
\algblock{Output}{EndOutput}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
%\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{minted}
% \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{datapie}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08emT\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\usepackage{xcolor}
% \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{boldline}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{listings}


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}

% \lstset{style=mystyle}
\lstset{escapeinside={*@}{@*},}
\lstset{language=Java,
        columns=fullflexible,
        basicstyle={\scriptsize\ttfamily},
        keywordstyle=\bfseries,
        %stringstyle=\color{Green},
        breaklines=true,
        commentstyle=\color{gray},
        morecomment=[s][\color{javadocblue}]{/**}{*/},
            breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2,
    xleftmargin=.2in,
}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=bf,skip=2pt}%set figure caption
\captionsetup[table]{font=bf,skip=2pt}%set table caption
\newcommand{\distance}{5pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{1pt}%set distance between figure/tables on the top/bottom with text
\setlength{\floatsep}{\distance}%set distance between figures or tables
\setlength{\intextsep}{\distance}%set distance between figures/tables in text with text
\setlength{\dbltextfloatsep}{\distance} %distance between a figure/table spanning both columns and the text;
\setlength{\dblfloatsep}{\distance} %distance between two figures/tables spanning both columns.

\begin{document}

\title{xxx}

\author{Ben Trovato}
\authornote{Both authors contributed equally to this research.}
\email{trovato@corporation.com}
\orcid{1234-5678-9012}
\author{G.K.M. Tobin}
\authornotemark[1]
\email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}
  \streetaddress{P.O. Box 1212}
  \city{Dublin}
  \state{Ohio}
  \country{USA}
  \postcode{43017-6221}
}

\author{Lars Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{The Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Group}
  \streetaddress{1 Th{\o}rv{\"a}ld Circle}
  \city{Hekla}
  \country{Iceland}}
\email{larst@affiliation.org}

\author{Valerie B\'eranger}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Inria Paris-Rocquencourt}
  \city{Rocquencourt}
  \country{France}
}

\renewcommand{\shortauthors}{Trovato and Tobin, et al.}
\begin{abstract}
xxx
\end{abstract}

\maketitle



\newpage
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format}
\bibliography{ref}


\end{document}
```

Could anyone tell me what is going on and what should I do now? I am a newbie to Tex. Thanks!

---

The screenshot of the VScode "Problems" tab:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the code that gives rise to the problem.

Comment: @instein would this work https://www.overleaf.com/read/tczydmdgmysg

Comment: @TejasShetty Yes, it can work on the Overleaf. It is actually an Overleaf project. What I want to do is to compile the Overleaf project locally so that I can write my paper without internet.

Comment: could you share the ref. bib. Actually, I am unable to reproduce your errors.

Comment: Also @instein, please share details of your local installation of Latex. Ie what version of MiKTeX, TexLive, are all packages installed? We can not proceed without this info.

Comment: @TejasShetty Here is my project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A3JfQ3I-89DDEF3XKuzMohGNZQERpEio/view?usp=sharing. You can unzip and use `code .` to let VSCode open it.

Comment: @TejasShetty I am using MiKTeX 21.6. I am not sure whether all package is installed (I think is all installed).

Comment: @Instein Can you post a screenshot of the VSCode "Problems" tab (Ctrl+Shift+M) please?

Comment: @Enevevet I updated the screenshot in the question description.

Comment: @Instein it looks like some parts of the error log are missing, could you please check this?

Comment: @Enevevet I uploaded the error log here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rr1QjTq1Gj8RUz1XaXAeMMHVANdVY9PE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 5):

The `-shell-escape` argument (which is needed for `minted` to do the pigmentation) seems to be missing when you compile the document.

Go to VSC settings (Ctrl/Cmd+,) and type `latex-workshop.latex.tools`. Click "Edit in `settings.json`".
Then add `"-shell-escape",` in `args` like below:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
      {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
          "-shell-escape", // HERE
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "-pdf",
          "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
          "%DOC%"
        ],
...
```

Finally, save `settings.json` and recompile you .pdf.